# I have a url which posts some data to the server. How do i convert it to alamofire post request method with all parameters mentioned in URL

Tags: ios, swift, url, post, alamofire

let url = "(InsertAsset)?customerID=(vmanagerappDelegate.cust_Id!)&assetTag=(self.txt_AssetTag.text! as String)&modelID=(modelObject)&statusID=(statusObject)&serial=(self.txt_Serial.text! as String)&assetName=(self.txt_AssetName.text! as String)&purchaseDate=(selectedPurchaseDate)&supplierID=(supplierObject)&purchaseCost=(purchaseCostObject)&warranty=(self.txt_Warranty.text! as String)&notes=(notesObject)&locationID=(locationObject)&ownerID=(ownerObject)&addUserID=(vmanagerappDelegate.userId as String)&saleEndDate=(self.txt_Sale_End_Date.text! as String)&softwareMaintainenceEndDate=(self.txt_Software_Maintainence_End_Date.text! as String)&supportEndDate=(self.txt_Support_End_Date.text! as String)&MacAddress=(self.txt_Mac_Address.text! as String)&sitekey=testing"

Comment: You should make a dictionary with all above params and send it to Alamo.request

Comment: Show us your current Alamofire code that you are trying?

Comment: http://dev.myvmanager.com/vManagerMobileWebService/api/Asset/Insert

This is the url and above ones are parameters. Please show me how to make a post request with above url and parameters

Comment: let params: [String : String] =
                ["customerID"    : vmanagerappDelegate.cust_Id,
                    "assetTag" : self.txt_AssetTag.text!,
                    "modelID"  : modelObject,
                    "statusID"     : statusObject,
                    "serial" : self.txt_Serial.text! as String,
etc

Like this i have written code for parameters...

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can create dictionary like following to send parameter as dictionary in Alamofire :

```
var dicParam = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()

dicParam[“customerID”] = vmanagerappDelegate.cust_Id!
dicParam[“assetTag”] = self.txt_AssetTag.text! as String
dicParam["modelID"] = modelObject
```

In Alamofire pass above dictionary as parameters along with your URL like following :

```
Alamofire.request("Your URL", method: .post, parameters: dicParam, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString), headers: nil).responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)

                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try creating a **dicitonary**

```
let params:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>  = ["customerID":vmanagerappDelegate.cust_Id!,"assetTag":self.txt_AssetTag.text,"modelID":modelObject]  //similarly add all params to Dict
```

if you want to add some headers create dicitonary **Header** for them too and pass in   `Alamofire.request(.POST,url,parameters: params,headers:Header,encoding: .JSON)`

a example for post request

```
func remotePOSTServiceWithParameters(urlString : String , params : Dictionary<String, AnyObject> , callback:(data: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?, error: NSError? ) -> Void)  {


         print("Request POST URL:\(urlString) PARAMS:\(params)")
        Alamofire.request(.POST,urlString,parameters: params,encoding: .JSON)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON {
                response in
                guard response.result.error == nil else {
                     print("Error for POST :\(urlString):\(response.result.error!)")
//                    

                    callback(data: nil , error: response.result.error! )
                    return
                }

                if let value = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(value)")
                    if let result = value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        print("Response for POST :\(urlString):\(value)")

                        callback(data:result , error: nil )
                    }
                }
          }

    }
```